# How to enable capture via amixer

Tags: ubuntu, microphone, capture

I want to activate a microphone on my machine via the command line. 
I use amixer for this.

```
amixer set "Front Mic" 66%
amixer set "Digital" 100%
amixer set "Front Mic Boost" 100%
amixer set "Capture" 100%
```

This set the volume settings. The problem is that capture is deactivated. Amixer displays this output:

Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 54
  Front Left: Capture 27 [50%] [-18.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 27 [50%] [-18.00dB] [off]

I can active capture via kmix after that amixer shows the channels as on. But the man pages don't show how to activate the channels via amixer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capture is activated via the following command:

```
amixer set "Capture" cap
```

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know that capture mode could be "off", although there is no visible indicator in `alsamixer`. In my case, a Cmedia 6206 based card, apart from setting `PCM Capture Source` (which can be done in `alsamixer`), I had to additionally "enable" the Line input (a dedicated control), using `amixer -c1 set Line cap`.